# Setting index route in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, routes, indexing

I've got Symfony2 installed, and a mostly working site, the only issue is I don't know how to set a default route. Currently, I access my index and other routes with the following URLs:

> www.example.com/app_dev.php/index
>
> www.example.com/app_dev.php/example_route

I'd like to have www.example.com default to the index route, so I can get the same results with the following URLs:

> www.example.com
>
> www.example.com/example_route

I'm running lighttpd as my web server. How can I configure lighttpd/Symfony2 to do this?

Comment: Symfony 3.2 , `app/config/routing.yml` add this code: 
`homepage:
    path:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:site:index }` //site is a SiteController in src/AppBundle/Controller/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just create a route that maps to the `/` pattern :

```
# app/config/routing.yml
homepage:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeHomeBundle:home:show }
```

This will route to whatever controller you specify.

Comment: Note: This won't work for Symfony 3+, use path instead of pattern

Answer (score 0):

Great Docs:

[How to Configure a Redirect without a custom Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_in_config.html)

[Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

I used below code to set home page route.It's working fine

Symfony version : Symfony 3.2.8

```
homepage:
    path:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Home:index}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me `Symfony 4.1.x`

Edit the file

```
# app/config/routes.yaml
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\YourIndexController::yourIndexFunction
```

There's
`App\Controller` is the `namespace` you declare at the start of the `Controller` class, and after is your class name and method name to route to.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by just removing the following from routing_dev.yml

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index }
```

That is assuming you have setup a default / route in a routing.yml file or by defining the route in a controller like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    return array('name' => '1');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The answer given by ManseUK is very much helpful but I have little elaboration

1)

```
# app/config/routing.yml
homepage:
    pattern:   /
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeHomeBundle:home:show }
```

2) rename the app_dev.php to index.php and this will route to the home page automatically

Comment: renaming app_dev.php to index.php is not a good idea as this entry point is use for development purpose, if you want to switch to production mode use app.php and use the htaccess to perform url rewriting

Comment: Agree: do not rename app_dev.php to index.php. That's there for development purposes. You can do it but I consider that a bad practice.