# How to set your own index route in symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

My issue is that I can't set my controller as the homepage. I have been searching a bit and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9125228/5126638) but it doesn't work when I runt it in production environment. It just works using dev environment.

This is my routing.yml:

```
homepage:
path: /
defaults: { _controller: DictionaryBundle:Grid:index}

app:
resource: @AppBundle/Controller/
type:     annotation

dictionary:
resource: @AppBundle/DictionaryBundle/Controller/
type:     annotation


fos_user:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"`
```

This is my routing routing_dev.yml:

```
_wdt:
resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
prefix:   /_profiler

 _configurator:
resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
prefix:   /_configurator

 _main:
resource: routing.yml

homepage:
path: /
defaults: { _controller: DictionaryBundle:Grid:index}
```

And this is my function:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{lang}", name = "showTranslationsGrid", defaults={"lang":"-"}, 
 * requirements={"lang":"-|en|fr|pt|it"})
 * @Template("AppBundle:Dictionary:grid.html.twig")
 * Renderiza la vista grid.html.twig que se encarga de generar el grid y cargar los datos
 */
public function indexAction($lang = "-")
{
    //utilizamos el servicio para obtener los belong
    $belongs = $this->forward('dictionary_util:getBelongsAction')->getContent();
    $languages = $this->forward('dictionary_util:getLanguagesAction')->getContent();
    $langs=json_decode($languages,true );

    return array('lang' => $lang, 'belongs'=> $belongs ,'languages'=> $languages );   
}
```

So, anybody know why something is rendering index.html.twig in app/Resources/views/default in production environment instead of using my controller and rendering my template like dev environment does?
I have also remove AcmeDemoBundle following this [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/remove.html) and I have cleared chache several times too.

I am working with symfony 2. I have updated to symfony 2.7 few days ago.

Comment: You are mixing route annotation and routing in yaml, I don't know how mush this is bad for Symfony but definitely is not good for your project structure. I suggest you to one or the other in each bundle.

Comment: Anyway, use `app/console --env=prod router:debug` to see all configured route in production enviroment, and `app/console --env=prod router:match /` to see the actual route which is chosen

Comment: Ok thanks =) this could be one the causes of my problem. Because I didn't  know about this Default controller using annotation. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the order of statements in rounting files. It was not working with production environment because homepage is at the top of the file, just below it refeers to the controllers inside AppBundle. There was DefaultController that came in default when I installed symfony (I though it only had AcmeDemoBundle). This controller was overriding previus declaration of homepage.
I won't remove the question just to make clear that order matters specially if you are working with other people in the same proyect.