# Symfony2 Set Default Home Page Route

Tags: symfony

In Symfony how do I change the default home page to a different route. Currently, my app is using public_home as the default route. This is the front page of my site, how would I change it to something else like public_blog?

Thanks

Comment: What dou you mean by *default home page*? Usually there is no such thing as a "configured home page". It's simply the first route which has `"/"` as it's path. Though there are ways to do automatic redirects, it's unclear what needs to be done in your case.

Comment: You're correct, I must've had a brain lapse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125228/setting-index-route-in-symfony-2

Answer (score 0):

The route name is an alias of path.

If you want your `public_blog` route as the "homepage" set this route path with `"/"`